# Create unique id by combining Charfield and ForeignKey from other model

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am having trouble with setting up the flow of my site with manytomany relationships.

For example, there are many models that have many types and vice versa. I have my URL set up site/model/typed/detail

Since typed and model are ManyToMany i can't pass on to my detail page.

I am thinking I can circumvent this by creating variables that literally link the model to type to let it be used as a unique identifier foreign key by detail. It would look something like: site/model/model_type/detail

However, I am having trouble pulling the values. If there is an easier way to solve this problem please let me know!

```
class typed(models.Model):
typed = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter MFG - Type')

model = models.ForeignKey('model', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

model_type = model + typed

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('typed-detail', args=[str(self.model), str(self.model_type)])

def __str__(self):
    return self.model_type
```

I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ForeignKey' and 'CharField'

Comment: Pete, I could be totally wrong but I'm not sure this is a common approach in modeling with Django's ORM. On the one hand, the easiest answer is to find a way to coerce the values of `model` and `typed` to strings, and then concatenate them, but without knowing more about your goal, and maybe an example or two of how they'd relate, I'm not sure that solves the larger problem. Have you looked into using Django's ManyToMany field type? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this

```
class typed(models.Model):
typed = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Enter MFG - Type')

model = models.ForeignKey('model', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('typed-detail', args=[str(self.model), "%s%s" % (self.model,self.typed)])
```

Comment: This is working I can tell it is passing the correct part through, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What is your `__str__`  method for the `model` Model?
If it's something like `return self.title` you can try this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.model)+ ' ' + str(self.typed)
```

Comment: What about the **get_absolute_url** part?